# Maintaining the scroll position when the list is being modified in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-listview, maintainscrollpositionon

I have a list thay displays elements with different heights (it can be also zero which mean the element is hidden), and I have a slider that controls the heights if the elements using a certain equation. The problem is, if I am standing on the 15th element for example, and i start increasing the height of the elements, the elements in the positions 0,...,14 "start pushing" the 15th element down in the list and I end up losing my position.
I tried using the jumpTo method of the scroll controller but the problem is because rhe heights are different, I cannot calculate the exact offsset that I need.
Is there a way to fix this problem?

I tried calculating the offsset but it did not work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It can indeed be challenging. One possible approach is to estimate element height and use `jumpTo` method to scroll to estimated offset.

Calculate the estimated offset by summarizing heights above the current position. Determine a buffer or padding to prevent close-up scrolling. Apply the offset using the `jumpTo` method of the `ScrollController`.

You can try this example

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  // Store the current slider value that determines element heights
  double _sliderValue = 0.0;

  // Store the estimated offset when the slider is changed
  double _estimatedOffset = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    // Calculate the estimated offset when scrolling
    _estimatedOffset = _calculateEstimatedOffset();
  }

  double _calculateEstimatedOffset() {
    double estimatedOffset = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _getCurrentElementIndex(); i++) {
      // Calculate the estimated height of each element
      double estimatedElementHeight = _calculateElementHeight(i);
      estimatedOffset += estimatedElementHeight;
    }

    // Add a buffer to the estimated offset
    double buffer = 20.0; // You can adjust this value
    estimatedOffset -= buffer;

    return estimatedOffset;
  }

  int _getCurrentElementIndex() {
    // Calculate the current element index based on your logic
    // This could be based on the slider value or other factors
    // For example: (_sliderValue * myList.length).toInt()
    return 0;
  }

  double _calculateElementHeight(int index) {
    // Calculate the estimated height of the element at the given index
    // This could be based on the slider value or other factors
    return 100.0; // Replace with your logic
  }

  void _updateSliderValue(double newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _sliderValue = newValue;
      _estimatedOffset = _calculateEstimatedOffset();
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_estimatedOffset);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // Build your list items based on the slider value and other factors
          // You can use the _sliderValue and _calculateElementHeight methods here
          return MyListItem();
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Slider(
        value: _sliderValue,
        onChanged: _updateSliderValue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```